# Unable to evaluate Formula between multiple sheets with poi Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
CellValue evalCellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
if(evalCellValue.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
{
        res = evalCellValue.getStringValue();
}
else if(evalCellValue.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN)
{
        res = Boolean.toString(evalCellValue.getBooleanValue());
}
if(evalCellValue.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
{
        res = Double.toString(evalCellValue.getNumberValue());
}
```

I want to get the evaluated value of a cell but it gives a #DIV/0! error
Formula on cell:

```
="IF($C$31<SUM($C$24:$C$25),$C$31*C24/SUM($C$24:$C$25),C24)"
```

Where:

- c-24 value is 0.00
- c-25 value is 0.00
- c- 31 is 0.00

So the formula with values will be:

```
"if(0<SUM(0:0),0*1/SUM(0:0),0)"
```

Looks like it's unable to calculate the if condition in the formula.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: =IF($C$31<SUM($C$24:$C$25),$C$31*C24/SUM($C$24:$C$25),C24).This the formula on the cell

Comment: "Looks like unable to calculate if condition in formula.": What means: it looks like? What happens? What `CellValue` are you getting from `FormulaEvaluator`?

Comment: from FormulaEvaluator i am getting #DIV/0! though there is already evaluted value in excel for that cell..I used cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()but it is laso giving 5 i.e. error

Comment: The `#DIV/0!` is absolute correct since you states "c-24 value is 0.00 c-25 value is 0.00" so `C24/SUM($C$24:$C$25)` evaluates to `0/0` which clearly is a division by zero.

Comment: there is if condition in formula c31<sum(c24:c25) hence it will never go for division it will directly print value of c24

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproducing this issue using `apache poi 4.0.0.`.

Having following Excel:

[image]

Formula in `A1` is `=IF($C$31<SUM($C$24:$C$25),$C$31*C24/SUM($C$24:$C$25),C24)`.

Using this code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelFormulaEvaluatorIFDIV0 {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("SAMPLE.xlsx"));
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Cell cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
  CellValue cellvalue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
  System.out.println(cell.getAddress() + ":" + cell + " evaluates to:" + cellvalue);

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Produces:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.0$ java -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* ExcelFormulaEvaluatorIFDIV0 
A1:IF($C$31<SUM($C$24:$C$25),$C$31*C24/SUM($C$24:$C$25),C24) evaluates to:org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [0.0]
```

So it evaluates fine.

Comment: i found that its not refreshing the excel formulas..that's why it is breaking.
I tried: XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb)

workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
   workbook.write(outputStream);
   workbook.close();